# When click on chekbox button, disable all input type value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

here i use a same address option in my page 
when i click on checkbox for same address my other input must disable
 my code:

```
<ul><input type="checkbox" name="same-address" /> Click for same address <br />Enter Address here: <input type="text" name="address" /> Enter City here: <input type="text" name="city" /> </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    $('#same').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parents('ul').find('li input[type="text"],select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $(this).parents('ul').find('li input[type="text"],select').removeAttr('disabled')
    }
});
```

[DEMO Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mVSPR/53/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** to select the input by type and use `.prop` to update the `disabled` state of your `input`:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled',this.checked);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zc3pX/1/)**

Comment: I would suggest scoping of input controls. This will disable all text inputs on the page.

Comment: but i dont want hide my upper side input type for address

Comment: can u explain in JS Fiddle

Comment: can i use a id here in which all input type hide on click and when click again it work

Comment: I don't get what you means. Can you rephrase your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input selector` for selecting all the input elements and in conjunction use `Prop`  for disabling the controls.

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        $('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled',this.checked);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<title>Test</title>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {  
      $('.SameAsBillingAddress').on('click',function(){

        if($(this).prop('checked'))
        {
            $('.Address2').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else
        {
            $('.Address2').prop('disabled', false);
        }
       });

}); 

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div>
<ul>
    <div style="height:30px; width:80%; margin-left:30px; clear:both;">
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" class="SameAsBillingAddress" />Same as Billing Address</div>
    <li>
        <label>House No.:</label>
        <input type="text" name="house no" class="Address2" placeholder="House No" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Street:</label>
        <input type="text" name="street" class="Address2" placeholder="Your Street" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>City</label>
        <input type="text" name="city" class="Address2" placeholder="Your City" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Zip:</label>
        <input type="text" name="zip" class="Address2" placeholder="Your Zip" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Country:</label>
        <select class="Address2">
            <option>India</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li style="float:right;">
        <label></label>
        <input type="submit" name="save" class="Address2" value="Save Details" />
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```